Correlation of columns based on different groups
I am trying to create a new dataframe that contains correlations by groups (three grouping variables). At the moment the problem is that the result contains always one and the same value (not different values by group).
We tried the following code: 
library(dplyr)
calc_cor <- function(df) {
  list(
    Cor1x2 = cor(df$var1, df$var2, method = "spearman", use = "pairwise.complete.obs"),
    Cor1x3 = cor(df$var1, df$var3, method = "spearman", use = "pairwise.complete.obs"),
    Cor1x4 = cor(df$var1, df$var4, method = "spearman", use = "pairwise.complete.obs"),
    Cor1x5 = cor(df$var1, df$var5, method = "spearman", use = "pairwise.complete.obs"),
    Cor2x3 = cor(df$var2, df$var3, method = "spearman", use = "pairwise.complete.obs"),
    Cor2x4 = cor(df$var2, df$var4, method = "spearman", use = "pairwise.complete.obs"),
    Cor2x5 = cor(df$var2, df$var5, method = "spearman", use = "pairwise.complete.obs"),
    Cor3x4 = cor(df$var3, df$var4, method = "spearman", use = "pairwise.complete.obs"),
    Cor3x5 = cor(df$var3, df$var5, method = "spearman", use = "pairwise.complete.obs"),
    Cor4x5 = cor(df$var4, df$var5, method = "spearman", use = "pairwise.complete.obs")
  )
}

# „group“ variable contains values from 1 to 55
# „meeting“ variable contains values from 1 to 6
# „session_phase“ variable contains values from 1 to 2.

result <- df %>%
  group_by(group, meeting, session_phase) %>%
  summarise(correlations = list(calc_cor(.))) %>%
  unnest_wider(correlations) %>%
  as.data.frame()

Each column, particularly var4 and var5, contains multiple NAs, they should be ignored so that the dataframe contains correlations from the values that could be used in the end.
Input Data
group   meeting session_phase   min  var1   var2    var3    var4    var5
1       1       1               0    0,3    0,19    0,26        
1       1       1               1    0,46   0,28    0,15        
1       1       1               2    0,42   0,39    0,22        
2       1       1               0    0,65   0,52    1,26        
2       1       1               1    0,94   0,36    1,22        
2       1       1               2    0,64   0,43    1,31        
2       1       1               3    0,55   0,32    1       0,95
…                               
1       1       2               0    0,55           0,82    0,79    0,95
1       1       2               1    1,02           1,02    1,09    0,7
1       1       2               2    0,69           0,71    0,95    0,54
2       1       2               0    0,59           0,31    0,7     0,37
2       1       2               1    0,34           0,2     0,54    0,59
2       1       2               2    0              0,55    0,2     0,37    
…                               
55      6       2               0    0,81           0       1,2     0,58
55      6       2               1    0,18           1,2     0,58    
55      6       2               2    0,27           1,14    0,39    


var1 to var5 now should be correlated with each other (var1 with var2, var1 with var3, var1 with var4 etc etc.), by the the grouping variables group, meeting, and session-phase so we end up with one correlation from var1 with var2 for group 1, meeting 1, session 1; one correlation from var1 with var2 for group 2, meeting 1, session 1, and so on.
False output
group   meeting session_phase   Cor1x2      Cor1x3      Cor1x4      Cor1x5      Cor2x3      Cor2x4      Cor2x5      Cor3x4      Cor3x5      Cor4x5
1       1       1               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
1       1       2               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
1       2       1               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
1       2       2               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
1       3       1               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
1       3       2               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
1       4       1               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
1       4       2               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
1       5       1               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
1       5       2               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
1       6       1               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
1       6       2               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
2       1       1               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
2       1       2               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
2       2       1               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
2       2       2               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
2       3       1               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
2       3       2               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
…                                               
55      6       1               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882
55      6       2               0,333523752 0,32578531  0,399857124 0,494264624 0,331031329 0,315864637 0,697428913 0,407285621 0,834623448 0,622817882


The expected output for Cor1x2 - Cor4x5 should be a different value for each row and column. I think that I forgot a step in order to correlate everything correctly. How can I fix this?

Pass cur_data into your function - also, corrr::correlate() will slim down the number of repeated calls to cor(). Requires a little processing to get everything in the format you want, but something like this works:
library(tidyverse)
library(corrr)

flatten_corr <- function(grp) {
  df <- correlate(cur_data(), quiet = TRUE) |> 
    shave() |> # take lower diagonal
    pivot_longer(-term) |> 
    filter(!is.na(value)) |> 
    unite(corr_pair, name, term, sep = "_x_") |> 
    t() |> 
    as_tibble() 
  
  df |> 
    set_names(df[1, ]) |> # use corr_pair for colnames
    slice_tail(n = 1) |> # drop corr_pair from the tibble
    mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric)) # t() converts to str, revert to numeric
}

data |> 
  group_by(group, meeting, session_phase) |> 
  summarise(correlations = flatten_corr(cur_data())) |> 
  unnest_wider(correlations)

Output:
# A tibble: 150 × 6
# Groups:   group, meeting [50]
   group meeting session_phase var1_x_var2 var1_x_var3 var2_x_var3
   <chr>   <int>         <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 a           1             1      0.333       -0.145    -0.00481
 2 a           1             2     -0.822        0.958    -0.674  
 3 a           1             3     -0.0976       0.434    -0.138  
 4 a           2             1      0.878       -0.139     0.0916 
 5 a           2             2      0.698        0.185     0.0922 
 6 a           2             3     -0.284       -0.259    -0.214  
 7 a           3             1     -0.708       -0.402     0.0499 
 8 a           3             2     -0.233        0.144     0.713  
 9 a           3             3     -0.538        0.606    -0.475  
10 a           4             1      0.747       -0.550    -0.433  
# … with 140 more rows

Example dataset:
set.seed(1L)
n <- 1000
data <- tibble(
  group = sample(letters[1:5], size = n, replace = TRUE),
  meeting = sample(1:10, size = n, replace = TRUE),
  session_phase = sample(1:3, size = n, replace = TRUE),
  var1 = rnorm(n = n),
  var2 = rnorm(n = n),
  var3 = rnorm(n = n)
)


Note: cur_data() is deprecated in favor of pick(), so @Onyambu's excellent answer will likely withstand the test of time longer than mine.

 data %>%
   group_by(group, meeting, session_phase)%>%
   reframe(cor(pick(starts_with('var')),method = 'spearman',
               use = 'pairwise.complete.obs') %>%
             as.data.frame.table(responseName = 'value'))%>%
   filter(as.character(Var1) < as.character(Var2)) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Var1:Var2)

# A tibble: 150 × 6
   group meeting session_phase var1_var2 var1_var3 var2_var3
   <chr>   <int>         <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 a           1             1   -0.452     0.143     0.119 
 2 a           1             2    0.3      -0.217    -0.45  
 3 a           1             3   -0.0857   -0.657    -0.429 
 4 a           2             1    0.833    -0.0833    0.183 
 5 a           2             2   -1        -0.4       0.4   
 6 a           2             3   -0.143     0.0857    0.0857
 7 a           3             1   -0.2      -0.714     0.829 
 8 a           3             2    0.393    -0.0714    0.214 
 9 a           3             3    0.143     0.6       0.486 
10 a           4             1   -0.238    -0.167    -0.524 
# ℹ 140 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows`enter code here`

